# Makehuman, mocap tool add-on, blender, scripting

Tags: python, add-on, blender

I trying to combine two programs: MakeHuman 1.06 (http://www.makehuman.org/) and Blender 2.57 (http://www.blender.org/).

I have been using the script for importing MH to blender and it works perfectly.

As I have imported one person, I simply want to use the add-on (mocap tool) (whose source code is provided here http://code.google.com/p/makehuman/source/browse/trunk/makehuman/importers/mhx/blender25x/space_view3d_mhx_mocap.py
)

and use the option **Load, Retarget, Simplify** to load my .bvh file.

Although, I can do it though the GUI, I can't find the write method/class to call, so that I could do it by script.

```
scn = bpy.context.scene

bpy.ops.mhx.mocap_load_retarget_simplify('INVOKE_DEFAULT', filepath = './cmuconvert-mb2-141-144/141/141_23.bvh')
```

but it doesn't seem to work...because of a warning

> Warning - no scene - scene properties not set

Could you please help me.?
I am quite stuck here:(

Comment: Rolled back the change - add it as a comment below and accept. That's the correct way to mark solved (it's ok to accept your own answers!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set 'EXEC_DEFAULT'

> bpy.ops.mhx.mocap_load_retarget_simplify('EXEC_DEFAULT', filepath =
>   filepath)